# Using an interface as a data contract for WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, datacontract

I'm looking for the best method of doing this.
I have a series of data types which I want to return in the WCF, under one method. This is why I have a MarkerInterface, so that I don't need 100s of ServiceContracts/Methods to just simply transform the data.

The unfortunate part is, all the DataContracts (such as currentbatch) are all unique, they have their unique set of properties. The reason I have a Transformer is that they all require some sort of Data Transformation based off of the dataset.

The transformer interface is as follows:

```
public interface IDataTransformer
{
    IMarkerInterface Transform(DataSet inDataSet_);
}
```

Then i have a transformer library for each datacontract (which i will explain below)

```
public class CurrentBatch_Transformer : IDataTransformer
{
}
```

This is One of the many datacontracts i will have, that implement IMarkerInterface.

```
[DataContract]
public class CurrentBatch : IMarkerInterface
{
    [DataMember]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool FlagLocked { get; set; }
}
```

So, because i have an IMarkerInterface; I can place everything in one method (GetDataUsingDataContract), and take in their respective transformer and a DataSet.

```
    public IMarkerInterface GetDataUsingDataContract(IDataTransformer composite, DataSet inData_)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }

        return composite.Transform(inData_);
    }
```

Again, my questions are:

1) Is this a good practice? If this isn't; why, and is there a better way of doing it?

2) Will the Interface get serialized during the WCF serialization? (I don't want it to get serialized, but wouldn't mind if it did).

Comment: Interfaces don't get serialized - they have no data and therefore there is nothing *to* serialize.  The client will see it as an `Object` (in .NET speak).  So if you're client is .NET, it will have to know how to cast the `Object` to the correct type.

Comment: @Tim is it safe to say then that the client wouldn't even know that an Interface has been implemented on the class?

Comment: Yes.  Depending on the language, the client may not even have the concept of a "class".  Unless, of course, the client has access to the assembly the data contracts are in (in which case it would be .NET) - then it would know the class implemented an interface.

Comment: @Tim I'm planning to use JSON serialization and send it over to a Javascript client :\, any heads up you can give me about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's acceptable solution, but you must let WCF know what kind of types you are going to use, because it should form WSDL document. You can use either ServiceKnownType attribute for ServiceContract, KnownType for data contract or add known types in config.

Here are examples:

1. **ServiceContract:**

   ```
   [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(Helper))]
   [ServiceContract()]
   public interface IService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       IMarkerInterface GetMarker();
   }

   static class Helper 
   {
       static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
       {
           return new Type[] { typeof(CurrentBatch) };
       }
   }
   ```
2. **KnownType:**

   ```
   [DataContract]
   [KnownType("GetKnownType")]  //there are few option of usage, you can apply for one concrete class: [KnownType(typeof(InheritedClass))]
   public class BaseClass
   {

       private static Type[] GetKnownType()
       {
           return return new Type[] { typeof(InheritedClass) };;
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Config file:**

   ```
   <system.runtime.serialization>
     <dataContractSerializer>
       <declaredTypes>
         <add type="MyProject.IMarkerInterface, MyProjectAssembly">
           <knownType type="MyProject.CurrentBatch, MyProjectAssembly"/>
         </add>
       </declaredTypes>
     </dataContractSerializer>
   </system.runtime.serialization>
   ```